# Validation rule - created date < FIXED DATE

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to add a line to a set of existing validation rules so they **only** apply to opportunities created prior to a fixed date. Let's say 10/31/2018. I thought it would be pretty straightforward as

`CreatedDate < 10/31/2018`

So the entire rule would read:

`ISPICKVAL ( StageName, "Demo")&&`

`Clinical_Buyer__c = FALSE&&`

`CreatedDate < 10/31/2018`

I keep getting the error that the '<' was expecting a `DateTime` received `Number`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike SOQL, formulas don't accept date literals. You'll need to construct your Date values using either the [`DATE()` function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5) :

> The DATE() function returns a Date value, given a year, month, and day. Numerical Y/M/D values and the YEAR(), MONTH(), and DAY() functions are valid parameters for DATE(). For example DATE( 2013, 6, 1 ) returns June 1, 2013

or the `DATEVALUE()` function, with a text parameter in ISO format:

> You can also convert text to a Date so you can use the string value with your other Date fields and formulas. You’ll want your text to be formatted as “YYYY-MM-DD”. Use this formula to return the Date value:
>
> DATEVALUE( "YYYY-MM-DD" )

If you want to compare the DateTime `CreatedDate` to a Date value, you can convert the field value with `DATEVALUE()`:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < DATEVALUE("2018-10-31")
```

Comment: I've attempted to use the DATE() function, but still getting an error:

`Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Date`


I had entered:

`CreatedDate < DATE(2018,10,1)`

Comment: You can convert the DateTime to a Date with the `DATEVALUE()` function, too.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you're meaning by converting to a DateTime, when this is all in a validation rule, there's got to be something I'm not understanding. I've tried adding a `DATEVALUE` but that doesn't seem to work either, perhaps I'm not using the correct syntax:


`ISPICKVAL ( StageName, "Negotiation")&&`

`Clinical_Acceptance__c = FALSE&&`

`CreatedDate < DATEVALUE("2018-10-31")`

The error I'm receiving: "Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Date"